# Console Navegador - JS - Rodando uma função em JS depois que a página carregar completamente.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Estou fazendo testes em JavaScript utilizando meu navegador e gostaria de fazer os seguintes passos:

- Criar um array que contem 3 abas

  ```
  janelas = Array();
  janelas.push(window.open(link_site1));
  janelas.push(window.open(link_site2));
  janelas.push(window.open(link_site3));
  ```
- Quero que assim que a página seja carregada completamente verifique se um campo existe:

  ```
      for (var key in janelas) {
  if(janela.document.readyState == 'complete'){
      console.log("Site:" + janela.location.href + "Status:" + janela.document.readyState);
      setTimeout(function(){
          try{
              if(janela.jQuery("h1:contains(Plugins)")[0].innerHTML == 'Plugins'){
                  if(janela.jQuery(hrefkey)[0]){
                      janela.jQuery(hrefkey)[0].click();
                      console.log('OK: ' + janela.location.href);
                  }else{
                      console.log('OK: Plugin ativo - ' + janela.location.href);
                  }
              };
          }catch(err){
              console.log('Não foi possivel acessar: ' + janela.location.href);
          }   
      },1000);
  }
  }
  ```

Porém mesmo utilizando `if(janela.document.readyState == 'complete'){}` ele esta executando todo conteúdo antes de carregar a página, fazendo com que a verificação `if(janela.jQuery("h1:contains(Plugins)")[0].innerHTML == 'Plugins'){}` sempre seja falsa.

============================================================

A função completa que estou tentando utilizar é essa :

```
            // Entrar em SITES 
    function abrirSites(){
        var filtro = 'site-info.php';
        var seletor = 'a.edit';
        var sites = document.querySelectorAll(seletor);
        janelas = Array();

        for (var key in sites){
            try {
                link_site = sites[key].href;
                if(!link_site.includes(filtro)){
                    janelas.push(window.open(link_site));
                    console.log(link_site);
                }
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }

        }
    }



    // Entrar na pagina de configurações de Plugin
    function ativarConfig(janelas,hrefkey){
        hrefkey = "[href='plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=wpsitesynccontent%2Fwpsitesynccontent.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=e8662b15b8']";
        for (var key in janelas){
            janela = janelas[key];
            // console.log(janela.location.href);
            if(!janela.location.href.includes("plugins.php")){
                janela.location.href = janela.location.href + 'plugins.php';
            };

            // Executar quando pagina estiver pronta 
            do{
                if(janela.document.readyState == 'complete'){
                    console.log("Site:" + janela.location.href + "Status:" + janela.document.readyState);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        try{
                            if(janela.jQuery("h1:contains(Plugins)")[0].innerHTML == 'Plugins'){
                                if(janela.jQuery(hrefkey)[0]){
                                    janela.jQuery(hrefkey)[0].click();
                                    console.log('OK: ' + janela.location.href);
                                }else{
                                    console.log('OK: Plugin ativo - ' + janela.location.href);
                                }
                            };
                        }catch(err){
                            console.log('Não foi possivel acessar: ' + janela.location.href);
                        }   
                    },1000);
                }
            }while(janela.document.readyState != 'complete');
        }
    }
    // Um de cada vez
    abrirSites();
    ativarConfig(janelas);
```

Comment: Por que não adiciona o atributo`defer` na tag `<script>`?

Comment: Eu to fazendo isso direto no navegador, não tenho um arquivo html